# How can I stop my R console and other R windows "flickering" after I updated my Mac OS to Sonoma 14.0?

Tags: r, macos, operating-system

I updated my Apple Silicon M1 Pro MacBook from Ventura to Sonoma 14.0. I have the latest version of R for Apple Silicon (4.3.1, "Beagle Scouts"). I also have the latest version of XQuartz (2.8.5).

On Ventura, my R setup worked fine ("classic" R.app GUI using console and script windows, not Rstudio). However, with Sonoma, when I try and toggle between the R console and an R script, the windows transition at very high speed between each other, making it nearly impossible to select either the console or the script.

This "flickering" phenomenon lasts for ~ 10-15 seconds each time I change windows between console and script, making the software nearly unusable.  Changing the screen refresh rate does not help.

The problem is specific for R.app and does not affect other software.

Any suggestions gratefully received. As suggested in comments, I will also post this question on the r-sig-mac mailing list.

Comment: Are you talking about R or RStudio?

Comment: "classic" R (console and scripts), not Rstudio

Comment: Is that   R from a command line in Terminal,  or  the R.app GUI that Simon maintains?  If so,  jump over to the r-sig-mac mailing list.  There are several skilled folk there who test and report on possible bugs with every MacOS "upgrade."

Comment: This question has been posted to r-sig-mac at https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2023-October/014866.html and there isn't a fix at the moment. FWIW I can reproduce this too so this is likely affecting everyone.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing happening lately and I've updated to the current Mac OS and also to the latest R.app version too. Anyone else find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears to be solved with a new update to Mac OS Sonoma (14.1.1). The original R.app (R 4.3.1 GUI) (not including the “hack” fix kindly provided by Simon Urbanek) now works like a charm. Deep sigh of relief all round.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a fix to test. Published in the r-sig-mac mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2023-October/014886.html
It solved the problem for me, but it is not yet officially signed.

Comment: Thank you for the notification! Simon Urbanek at r-sig-mac mailing list says that this fix is a bit of a "hack". The root cause of the flickering phenomenon is due to macOS Sonoma sending multiple incorrect notifications of windows closing to the R.app. Why these notifications are occurring is still a mystery, but Simon has provided a provisional fix to the R.app that simply ignores the notifications. But a more permanent solution that tackles the root cause of the problem would be preferable.